# How do I make a cross table select in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with building SQL query.

I have 4 tables: Sellers, Goods, Projects and Sales.

Sellers table has following structure:

```
SellerID (int) PK
SellerName (nvarchar)
SellerStatus (int)
SellerCity (nvarchar)
```

Goods:

```
GoodsID (int) PK
GoodsTitle (nvarchar)
GoodsColor (nvarchar)
GoodsSize (int)
GoodsCity (nvarchar)
```

Projects:

```
ProjectID (int) PK
ProjectTitle (nvarchar)
ProjectCity (nvarchar)
```

Sales:

```
SellerID (int)
GoodsID (int)
ProjectID (int)
Price (int)
```

I need to get Sellers ID's, which distribute same Goods to all Projects.

Can anybody help me with query?
I use MSSQL.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post some of the code you already have?

Comment: Please use the `Code` tags next time when you show code or database objects; it formats them nicely and makes them much easier to read.

Comment: I have no any idea how to implement it, so I have nothing to show.

Comment: Just to be clear, for each seller, you want to find any goods that the seller has in all projects?  For example, if seller 5 has projects 1, 2 and 3, and if Good 1 is sold in project 1 and 2, but Good 2 is sold in project 1, 2 and 3, you want to return Seller 5, Good 2?

Comment: you're right. I need find every seller, which have some goods, and sell at least one of them to all projects

Comment: @Vitali: same goods to ALL project, or same goods to the projects they're currently involved with in the Sales table? Include sellers with just one project, or must have 1+ projects?

Comment: @p.campbell: projects they're currently involved with in the Sales table. Sellers with one project are also needed.

LittleBobbyTables has more clear description in his(her?) comment. I'm russian-speaking and sometimes can't express my question in clear form. Sorry

Comment: @Vitali: you've got some contradictory requirements, it seems. Either "distribute same Goods to all Projects" (*ALL* from the question), or which Goods are common to all Projects (as in your response to BobbyTables. Please edit your question with some sample data, and the expected output. That'll be the best way to answer your question thoroughly and without confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I honestly aint sure if i have understood exactly all the requirements (i did go through all the comments but am a bit confused after that). However, if you want ALL Sellers who have SOLD atleast 1 GOODs to ALL projects, then the below might give you that, i think.

Can you try it out and see if it does? I really have no access to a DB to try it out right now

Also, in case it isnt meeting some requirement which i have missed, please feel free to elaborate a bit, maybe using example data - which might make it simpler for all.

```
SELECT SellerID FROM SALES
GROUP BY SellerID, GoodsID
HAVING COUNT(ProjectID) = SELECT count(ProjectID) FROM Projects
```

Comment: +1 with the mention that *(SellerID, GoodsID, ProjectID)* must be *unique*, i.e. a Seller can't sale the same Good to the same Project twice (with the same price or a different one).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, let me know if it's the right direction:

```
select SellerID
from   Sales s1 join Goods g1 on (GoodsID)
where  not exists 
    (select SellerID, GoodID
     from Sales s2
        join Goods g2 on (GoodsID)
        left join Sales on (SellerID, GoodsID)
     where s1.Seller = s2.Seller and 
           g1.GoodsID = g2.GoodsID and
           Sales.ProjectID is null)
```

Comment: Something is wrong with it, SQL managment studio throws errors near Where expression at lines 3 and 7 (expression's type must be logic)